Add pagenumber to azure search index fields
I am using Azure Integrated vectorization for our document extraction and wondering if there is a way that I can add original page number which chunk belongs to it. This will help when we show the citation and navigate user to direct page of the pdf rather than showing the full original pdf. Is there any way to do it? I am using below sample code in c#.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-search-vector-samples/blob/main/demo-dotnet/DotNetIntegratedVectorizationDemo/readme.md

There is an option called imageAction which is configured in indexer.
It gives you the page number.
When you set that property to generateNormalizedImages you will get below data in the context /document/normalized_images/*.
[
  {
    "data": "BASE64 ENCODED STRING OF A JPEG IMAGE",
    "width": 500,
    "height": 300,
    "originalWidth": 5000,  
    "originalHeight": 3000,
    "rotationFromOriginal": 90,
    "contentOffset": 500,
    "pageNumber": 2
  }
]

To get page number you give like this /document/normalized_images/*/pageNumber but this will be list of objects so you need to do index projection on your secondary index.
Next, if you handling the data in chunks then the context will be /document/normalized_images/*/pages
Next, send this to OcrSkill and ImageAnalysisSkill  for further analysis and do index projections with the output of this skillset.
Note: Make sure you give /document/normalized_images/* for parameter sourceContext.

thanks for the reply yeah i did see that you can convert the document into images but i feel just to get page number i need to convert my document to image. Is that the only way? also this page number will be the original page number as document could be split into multiple pages.

also how does overalp works incase of OCR skill as we need to carry some context  from one page to another page

To get pagenumber as of now this is the only way. or if you are having the pagenumber as content in each page the extract it  using custom web api skill.
